# ElasticSearch faceted search for a multilingual field

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I have a Elasticsearch DSL query like below,

```
query = {
     "query": {"query_string": {"query": "%s" % q}},
        "facets": {"destination": {
            "terms": {"field": "destination"}}}}
```

where my destination indexed as a multilingual field like below,

```
destination': {u'fr': u'Portland', u'en': u'Portland'}
```

So my facets result comes empty because of this multingual issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = {
     "query": {"query_string": {"query": "%s" % q}},
        "facets": {"destination": {
            "terms": {"field": "destination.en"}}}}
```

worked for me

Comment: What is the mapping of destination? I am asumming that destination has a scalable property structure so it can handle on demand properties like: destination.en, destination.fr, destination.du etc..